# Airflow 2.0 errors when creating users via CLI

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, airflow, airflow-2.x

We are getting spun up with Airflow 2.0 but are running into a weird issue when creating the initial admin user. The installation of Airflow and running `airflow db init` appear to run fine, but when we run the command `airflow users create -u <username> --use-random-password -f <firstname> -l <lastname> -r Admin -e <emailaddress>` we get the error listed below repeated about 50 times:

```
[2021-01-27 20:42:13,801] {base.py:593} ERROR - Add Permission on View Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'permissions'
[2021-01-27 20:42:14,261] {base.py:600} ERROR - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'permissions'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask_appbuilder/base.py", line 598, in _add_permissions_menu
    self.sm.add_permissions_menu(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/manager.py", line 1241, in add_permissions_menu
    self.add_permission_role(role_admin, pv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/sqla/manager.py", line 594, in add_permission_role
    if perm_view and perm_view not in role.permissions:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'permissions'
```

We haven't been able to find any documentation so we're really not sure what to do. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That feels like there is no 'Admin' role which is weird. 

Try running from scratch in a virtual environment and see if that works

Comment: Yeah, this is what happens when we run from scratch. It's a completely fresh database

Comment: How did you install airflow? Did you use the constraints file

`pip install 'apache-airflow==2.0.0' -c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.0.0/constraints-3.7.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Our issue was that we weren't setting the webconfig ldap settings correctly in the shell we were running the create command.